# can i convert an activity into a floating window?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

I know that floating windows are services... But is there a way to convert an activity/fragment into a floating window?

My Sample Code of FloatingWindow

```
public class FloatingWindow extends Service{
WindowManager wm;
LinearLayout ll;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParameteres = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 400);
    ll.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(66,255,0,0));
    ll.setLayoutParams(layoutParameteres);

    final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            500, 200, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    parameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
    parameters.x = 0;
    parameters.y = 0;

    Button stop = new Button(this);
    stop.setText("Stop");
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams btnParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    stop.setLayoutParams(btnParameters);

    ll.addView(stop);
    wm.addView(ll, parameters);

    ll.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams updatedParameters = parameters;
        double x;
        double y;
        double pressedX;
        double pressedY;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    x = updatedParameters.x;
                    y = updatedParameters.y;

                    pressedX = event.getRawX();
                    pressedY = event.getRawY();

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    updatedParameters.x = (int) (x + (event.getRawX() - pressedX));
                    updatedParameters.y = (int) (y + (event.getRawY() - pressedY));

                    wm.updateViewLayout(ll, updatedParameters);

                default:
                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wm.removeView(ll);
            stopSelf();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stopSelf();
}
```

So i have an activity and i want to convert that into a floating window service...... is that possible somehow? Please help me out...... Thanks......

Error

[image]

On the line -         `myview = li.inflate(R.layout.activity_customize, null); //` your layout here

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/black">

        <TextView
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:text="Customise"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_below="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/actionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/color"
            android:paddingVertical="10dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:text="Color"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/font"
            android:paddingVertical="10dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Font"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/size"
            android:paddingVertical="10dp"
            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:text="Size"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This was the simplest activity in my project so tried with this

Comment: AFAIK you cant, but you can use that `acitvity's` xml as a floating window, using service, and perform action on UI also

Comment: How can i do that?? @AbdulKawee

Comment: check answer below :)

Comment: what is your requirement ?

Comment: can you post `activity_customize` layout here pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to inflate a UI in `service`

```
View myview;

li= (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            //WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,// | WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

     /////////////////////////Another params


WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
           PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)

    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.TOP;
    myview = li.inflate(R.layout.xyz, null); // your layout here    

    wm.addView(myview, params);
```

For adding some `cliclListener`

```
ImageView playButton = (ImageView) myview.findViewById(R.id.play_btn);
playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       Toast.makeText(FloatingViewService.this, "Playing the song.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
});

//change this as your per your requirement
```

Hope this solves your problem

Comment: myview isnt defined... what is myview?

Comment: Getting an error... look to my edited question please

Comment: there is a problem with your `activity_customize` layout, post it

Comment: Done... check please

Comment: Yeah it is... error cant be with the layout because i tried many layouts and got the same error

Comment: @MichelleKinsten please remove `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` and check in service

Comment: @MichelleKinsten and also, i have edited some code, for `params` please check this also

Comment: Yea it worked after removing appbar... thanks a lot mate...also one last question... how can i set clicklisteners>

Comment: Awesome, thats easy part, you can set listeners like you do in adapters and fragments, i am editing answer adding some sample for listener

Comment: Im not able to implement clicklisteners with this... are u sure this is the right method? Can u help me out please if its not a problem @AbdulKawee

Comment: There is no error... the onclick isnt working thats all... i gooogled and i dont think u can implement onclick on a view... im not sure though

Comment: you have to change the flags in layout

Comment: @MichelleKinsten check i have added more params, try them

Comment: Can u also show an example for implementing onClick... like i initialised a button... then just set onclicklistener and the usual way isnt working

Answer (score 0):

Below code will start a service with a layout

```
val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext)
if (layoutInflater != null) {
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.service_floating_windows, null, false)

    wm!!.addView(view, parameters)

    touchMovementOfTheFloatingWindow(parameters)
}
```

Design your layout that you want to show. Then start your service from anywhere

```
class Asd : Service() {
private var wm: WindowManager? = null
private var view: View? = null
override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    wm = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
    val parameters: WindowManager.LayoutParams
    val minHW = U.getScreenMinHW(this)

    parameters = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 25) {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                minHW * 2 / 3, minHW * 2 / 3,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
    } else {
        WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                minHW * 2 / 3, minHW * 2 / 3,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT)
    }

    parameters.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
    parameters.x = 0
    parameters.y = 100

    val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext)
    if (layoutInflater != null) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.service_floating_windows, null, false)

        wm!!.addView(view, parameters)

        touchMovementOfTheFloatingWindow(parameters)
    }

}


private fun touchMovementOfTheFloatingWindow(parameters: WindowManager.LayoutParams) {
    view!!.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {
        internal var updatedParameters = parameters
        internal var x: Double = 0.toDouble()
        internal var y: Double = 0.toDouble()
        internal var pressedX: Double = 0.toDouble()
        internal var pressedY: Double = 0.toDouble()

        override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {

            when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    x = updatedParameters.x.toDouble()
                    y = updatedParameters.y.toDouble()
                    pressedX = event.rawX.toDouble()
                    pressedY = event.rawY.toDouble()
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                    updatedParameters.x = (x + (event.rawX - pressedX)).toInt()
                    updatedParameters.y = (y + (event.rawY - pressedY)).toInt()

                    wm!!.updateViewLayout(view, updatedParameters)
                }

                else -> {
                }
            }

            return false
        }
    })
}


override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY
}}
```

Comment: whats d reason for getting an inflate exception on the line ......inflate(R.layout.abc,null).....

Comment: @MichelleKinsten You have to create a layout. Then inflate.

Comment: can i implement onClicklisteners from the layout that i have inflated???